# How to effectively detect outliers in a feature space?

Tags: algorithms, average

Suppose I have feature vectors of $N$ dimension. However, there are outliers in these vectors, meaning that it has an Euclidean distance larger than certain threshold $K$ from the true center of these feature vectors. These outliers is just a small proportion of the total number of feature vectors. How can I effectively detect these outliers?

At first, I am thinking of taking average as the pseudo center and than remove those vectors that are larger than certain threshold $K'$. However, I am not sure if this method works. Will there be cases where taking average will fail? If so, how can I solve this problem effectively without incurring too much computational costs?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Detection

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I know about this. I am just wondering if taking average as center will fail in any case? My problem is that my dataset is very large so computational time is one of my constraint

Comment: "outlier" is ill-defined, so you can't say for sure whether a method will succeed/fail. If you define a "true outlier" as being further away from the "true center" than a certain threshold, it all comes down to what method you use to evaluate the "true center" and how that estimate relates to the actual "true center". With no knowledge on how your dataset is generated, there are no correct answer to that question.

Comment: Actually to give more context, if you can interpret your "true center" as the mean/average point of your theoretical dataset, then the law of large numbers guarantee that the empiric average on exact sample points converges to that mean. If your dataset was acquired by some measurement, your data points may have some noise, but many popular noise models have no influence on the convergence. The problem is whether the noise model is realistic with respect to your actual data. Which is the basis for why context matters a lot for outliers.